# Retrieving currently logged in user's title/salutation fails

Tags: netsuite, suitecommerce

In NetSuite SuiteCommerce Advanced I am attempting to get the currently logged in users title (Mr, Mrs, etc.).

I am using the `Commerce API` and the function `Customer::getFieldValues()`. I am retrieving the column/field name [`salutation`](https://debugger.na2.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_2/script/record/customer.html#field_salutation). When I execute this function it returns an empty object when it should return the users title/salutation. *Note: I have confirmed the user has a title/salutation set as 'Mr'*.

Any advice why SCA is not returning the user's title? This is sooo annoying of NS!

*****`Modules\MyOverrides\ProfileOverrides@1.0.0\SuiteScript\Profile.Model.js`:

```
define('Profile.Model',['SC.Model', 'underscore', 'Utils'], function (SCModel,  _,  Utils)
{
    'use strict';

    return SCModel.extend({
        name: 'Profile'

    ,   get: function ()
        {
            //You can get the profile information only if you are logged in.
            if (this.isLoggedIn && this.isSecure)
            {

                // Retrieve the currently logged in users saluation (eg Sir, Mr, Mrs, etc.)
                // Why on earth does NS not return this!!!
                var profile = customer.getFieldValues(['salutation']);
                console.log("PROFILE", profile); // outputs "PROFILE {}"

    ...
```

***Edit**: I incorrectly stated the file was 
`Modules\MyOverrides\AccountOverrides@1.0.0\SuiteScript\Account.Model.js`: when it is actually `Modules\MyOverrides\ProfileOverrides@1.0.0\SuiteScript\Profile.Model.js`.

Comment: Could you show where are you declaring customer and session please?

Comment: @AdolfoGarza thanks for your comment. FYI I incorrectly stated the file was `Modules\...\Account.Model.js` when it is actually `Modules\...\Profile.Model.js`. Re; where I declare `customer` and `session`, I don't. If you are familiar with the SCA suitescript file `Modules\suitecommerce\Profile@2.1.0\SuiteScript\Profile.Model.js` you'll see its `get` function also doesn't declare these variables. So I assume they are global. The user is logged in and secure because the code executes and can retrieve the users first name, last name, etc. Just `salutation` fails.